# Loader content always null

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I load successfully an external image using a Loader class but every time i trace the loader.content property is found null. Why?

ps: Actually, i'm trying to get the bitmapdata from a loader object.

Comment: got some sample code to illustrate the issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure you didn't accidentally attach the listener to the loader itself as opposed to loader's **contentLoaderInfo** property
2. You should be able to access it as **Bitmap(loader.content).bitmapData** in the **Event.COMPLETE** handler.